# Disordered Vector of Symbols on Ggplot2 Grid Label

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I want to place the following in the same order `$\ph_1 = 0.4$, $\ph_2 = 0.4$` in `column 1` `$\ph_1 = 0.45$, $\ph_2 = 0.45$` in `column 2` and `$\ph_1 = 0.35$, $\ph_2 = 0.5$` in `column 3`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
set.seed(199)
MB_RMSE_sd1_phi0.8 <-  runif(4, min = 0, max = 2)
TMB_RMSE_sd1_phi0.8 <- runif(4, min = 0, max = 2)
MB_RMSE_sd1_phi0.9 <-  runif(4, min = 0, max = 2)
TMB_RMSE_sd1_phi0.9 <- runif(4, min = 0, max = 2)
MB_RMSE_sd1_phi0.95 <-  runif(4, min = 0, max = 2)
TMB_RMSE_sd1_phi0.95 <- runif(4, min = 0, max = 2)

MB_RMSE_sd3_phi0.8 <-  runif(4, min = 2, max = 5)
TMB_RMSE_sd3_phi0.8 <- runif(4, min = 2, max = 5)
MB_RMSE_sd3_phi0.9 <-  runif(4, min = 2, max = 5)
TMB_RMSE_sd3_phi0.9 <- runif(4, min = 2, max = 5)
MB_RMSE_sd3_phi0.95 <-  runif(4, min = 2, max = 5)
TMB_RMSE_sd3_phi0.95 <- runif(4, min = 2, max = 5)

MB_RMSE_sd5_phi0.8 <- runif(4, min = 5, max = 10)
TMB_RMSE_sd5_phi0.8 <- runif(4, min = 5, max = 10)
MB_RMSE_sd5_phi0.9 <- runif(4, min = 5, max = 10)
TMB_RMSE_sd5_phi0.9 <- runif(4, min = 5, max = 10)
MB_RMSE_sd5_phi0.95 <- runif(4, min = 5, max = 10)
TMB_RMSE_sd5_phi0.95 <- runif(4, min = 5, max = 10)

MB_RMSE_sd10_phi0.8 <-  runif(4, min = 7, max = 16)
TMB_RMSE_sd10_phi0.8 <- runif(4, min = 7, max = 16)
MB_RMSE_sd10_phi0.9 <-  runif(4, min = 7, max = 16)
TMB_RMSE_sd10_phi0.9 <- runif(4, min = 7, max = 16)
MB_RMSE_sd10_phi0.95 <-  runif(4, min = 7, max = 16)
TMB_RMSE_sd10_phi0.95 <- runif(4, min = 7, max = 16)
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

# Instead of using a character vector make your phi column a list column.

AR2_RMSE_NEWDAT <- tibble::tibble(
  RMSE = AR2_RMSE_reshapp1$value,
  year = AR2_RMSE_reshapp1$ID,
  n = rep(rep(c("10", "15", "20", "25"), each = 1), 24),
  Methods = rep(rep(c("MBB", "MBBR"), each = 4), 12),
  sd = rep(rep(c(1, 3, 5, 10), each = 24), 1),
  phi = rep(rep(list(c(0.4, 0.4), c(0.45, 0.45), c(0.35, 0.6)), each = 8), 4)
)

AR2_RMSE_NEWDAT$sd <- factor(AR2_RMSE_NEWDAT$sd, levels = AR2_RMSE_NEWDAT$sd, labels =         
paste("sd ==", AR2_RMSE_NEWDAT$sd))
AR2_RMSE_NEWDAT$year <- factor(AR2_RMSE_NEWDAT$year, levels = AR2_RMSE_NEWDAT$year[1:4])
AR2_RMSE_NEWDAT$n <- factor(AR2_RMSE_NEWDAT$n, levels = AR2_RMSE_NEWDAT$n[1:4])

# Create the labels
AR2_RMSE_NEWDAT$phi <- purrr::map_chr(AR2_RMSE_NEWDAT$phi, function(x) {
  paste(paste0("varphi[", seq_along(x), "]==", x), collapse = "*textstyle(',')~", sep = "")
})

ggplot(AR2_RMSE_NEWDAT, aes(x = n, y = RMSE, group = Methods)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = Methods)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = Methods)) +
  xlab("Sample Size(n)") +
  ylab("RMSE") +
  ggplot2::facet_grid(sd ~ phi, scales = "free_y", labeller = label_parsed) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.0)) +
  theme_bw(18) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -90, vjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = rel(1.00), angle = 0)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = rel(.55), angle = 90)) +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 12), legend.text = element_text(size = 10))
```

This is [image: what I have]

**What I Want**

This is [image: what I want]

Comment: Try this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65410930/11570343) `factor(phi, levels=c('lvl1','lvl2','lvl3'))`

Comment: See my update on your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73670743/12993861